# Finite State - Understand state transition function

Tags: logic, formal-languages, finite-automata

Context: Finite State, State transition system -> state transition function

I'm trying to understand what is being meant by this formula:

$γ:S \times A \times E \to 2^S$

The text above (translated from German into english) says:

> How a state can be changed is described by a (yet still unknown)
>   function which calculates a possible next state which is triggered by
>   an action or an exogenous event.

I understand that $S$ is a set of states, $A$ a set of Actions and $E$ a set of exogenous events but what does $2^S$ say?

Comment: My first impression is that `2^S` means the power set of $S$, the family of subsets of $S$.  It would improve your Question to cite your source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2^S$ is the power set of $S$. $\gamma : S \times A \times E \to 2^S $ means that from a state $s$ the transition system goes to a *set* of states depending on what action $a \in A$ and event $e \in E$ are chosen. This means that the transition system is nondeterministic because from one state we can go to many different states with the same action and event.

Comment: I wonder what you do after the 'transition'. I guess you have to pinpoint what it is before 'turning the crank' again. (+1)

Comment: Here's the Wikipedia page on [nondeterministic finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), which explains the relationship to deterministic finite automata in some detail, i.e. what happens "before 'turning the crank' again".